# Outlook Web-Addin .displayNewMessageForm() does not work. How to use correctly?

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

I have created a WebAddin, where you enter some details in a taskpane. That Taskpane has a Button, which should open an new Message Form trough the API-Function `Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm();`

HTML for the Button:

`<button type="button" onclick="OpenNewEMailDialog()">doIt</button>`

JS-Code:

```
function OpenNewEMailDialog()
{
    Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm();
}
```

But nothing happens and i do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method expects a 'parameters' argument. All parameters are optional, but the argument is expected. `Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageForm({});` should work!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.6#displaynewmessageform-parameters-

Comment: thanks it works! i understood the usage of the parameters wrong.